# Change color of font after specific code

Tags: javascript, html, colors

When a code is typed in like ^1 in a textarea i want the font color of any text after that code to be changed to whatever color the ^1 is assigned to,

As of now i have the following:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<textarea id="text" onkeypressed="changecolor()"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function changecolor() { //code here }
```

so basically when i type in ^1 and the color blue is assigned to that code, the text after that code will be in the color blue, but when a second code is typed in; example ^2 the text after that will be the color that is assigned to that code,

I know very well how to insert data into a database, but i need to beable to find a way of getting the raw data; i.e the data that was orginally typed into the textarea with the codes like ^1 and ^2

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant target specific fragments of text in a textarea. What you want to do can't be done of my knowing, unless you monitor its content and add an abstract div layer to output styled html from it.
Many wysiwyg text editors do it like this, or use the 'contenteditable' attribute to allow html editing in modern browsers...
You can start like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var display, input, displayHtml;
    function init(){
       display = document.getElementById('display');
       input = document.getElementById('input');
    }
    function onContentChange(){
        displayHtml = parseContent(this.value);
        display.innerHtml = displayHtml;
    }
    function parseContent(text){
        var html = ... // Generate html according to content
        return html;
    }
    document.onload=init;
</script>
```

html:

```
<textarea id='input' onkeypress="javascript:onContentChange" />
<div id='display'></div>
```

Comment: As I said they use the textarea to allow user input, but hide it and add a div element in its place. They subscribe to the textarea 'change' event to permanently update the div's content accordingly. Each time something is typed, the content is parsed and rendered within span,p,h1,h2 tags inside the main div accordingly. You can just use spans and divs to acchieve what you want.

Comment: could u please give me a simple example of how this can be achieved, Thanks very much!

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a basic idea on how it can be achieved. You should use jQuery or another shortcut library.

Comment: Thank you very much, i gave u the most helpful answer!! P.S. textareas need to be closed dont they.. :D

Comment: This is not copy-paste code, it's just the general idea... You have quiet a developement ahead of you to achieve what you want...